# splitting list, extracting an element and adding it in python

Tags: python, list, join, split, addition

I am new in python.

I have a list with seperator of "::" and it seems like that;

> 1::Erin Burkovich (2000)::Drama
>   2::Assassins (1995)::Thriller

I want to split them by "::" and extract the year from name and add it into the end of the line. Each movie has it own index.

Desired list seems like;

> 1::Erin Burkovich:Drama::2000
>   2::Assasins:Thriller:1995

I have below code:

```
for i in movies:
    movie_id,movie_title,movie_genre=i.split("::")
    movie_year=((movie_title.split(" "))[-1]).replace("(","").replace(")","")
    movies.insert(-1, movie_year)
```

but it doesn't work at all.

Any help ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `it doesn't work at all` even mean? Stack trace?

Comment: @MikeTung It's infinite loop. OP is expanding the list while iterating on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're having *infinite loop*, because when you add an item, your loop needs to iterate on more items, and then you're adding another item...

You should create a new list with the result.

Also, you can extract the list in a much easier way:

```
movie_year = re.findall('\d+', '(2000)')
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of splitting, you can use `re.findall` to grab all alphanumeric characters, including whitespace, and then regroup:

```
import re
s = ['1::Erin Burkovich (2000)::Drama', '2::Assassins (1995)::Thriller']
new_data = [re.sub('\s(?=\:)', '', "{}::{}:{}:{}".format(id, name, type, year)) for id, name, year, type in [re.findall('[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+', i) for i in s]]
```

Output:

```
['1::Erin Burkovich:Drama:2000', '2::Assassins:Thriller:1995']
```

Answer (score 0):

Another (probably less elegant) way:

```
for i in movies:
    split_list = i.split("::")
    movie_id = split_list[0]
    movie_title = split_list[1].split('(')
    movie_genre = split_list[2]
    print movie_id + '::' + movie_title[0].strip() + "::" + movie_genre + "::" + movie_title[1].strip(')')
```

Answer (score 0):

For python 3.6,check out this

```
a="""1::Erin Burkovich (2000)::Drama
2::Assassins (1995)::Thriller"""
a=a.split("\n")
c=[]
for b in range(len(a)):
    g=[]
    d=a[b].split("::")
    e=d[1].split(" (")[1].split(")")[0]
    f=d[1].split(" (")[0]
    g.append(d[0])
    g.append(f)
    g.append(d[2])
    g.append(e)
    h="::".join(g)
    c.append(h)
print("\n".join(c))
```

OUTPUT::

```
1::Erin Burkovich::Drama::2000
2::Assassins::Thriller::1995
```

Answer (score 0):

Many issues,

- `split` doesn't return a tuple but a list, so it can't be assigned directly
- movie year split is fine but you aren't removing the year from the original title
- inserting into movies array is not a good idea, you need to replace the array element instead

I've rewritten the code based on what you wanted, hope it helps

```
movies=["1::Erin Burkovich (2000)::Drama", "2::Assassins (1995)::Thriller"]

for i in range(len(movies)):
    movie_details=movies[i].split("::")
    print movie_details
    movie_id=movie_details[0]
    movie_title=movie_details[1]
    movie_genre=movie_details[2]
    movie_title_parts=movie_title.split(" ")
    movie_year=((movie_title_parts[-1]).replace("(","").replace(")",""))
    del movie_title_parts[-1]
    movie_title=" ".join(movie_title_parts)
    print movie_title+", "+movie_year
    movies[i]=movie_id+"::"+movie_title+"::"+movie_genre+"::"+movie_year
```